# Polling for Jobs issue on Jenkins initiated from AWS pipeline

Tags: jenkins, aws-codepipeline

I am facing following issue on Jenkins.
What I am doing is that I have setup a pipeline on AWS and it is all working fine with deployments etc.
I have setup a Jenkins project already on a server separately for the testing purpose of APIs test cases.

What I am doing connecting the Jenkins server with the Build stage of the AWS. All seem to go smooth but on the Jenkins server I found the following issue.

To make it simple, I just tried to execute the date in a variable and print it (echo) and comment out the original running script command. In build execute shell area only following two command are written.

now='date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"'
echo $now

> [AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Polling for jobs for action type id: [Owner:
> Custom, Category: Test, Provider: Jenkins_November, Version: 1,
> ProjectName: Chiragh_Tests] ERROR: Failed to record SCM polling for
> hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@5f5daea6[Chiragh_Tests]
> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Unable to unmarshall exception
> response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: AWSCodePipeline;
> Status Code: 404; Error Code: null; Request ID: null) at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1799)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1359)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.codepipeline.AWSCodePipelineClient.doInvoke(AWSCodePipelineClient.java:3040)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.codepipeline.AWSCodePipelineClient.invoke(AWSCodePipelineClient.java:3007)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.codepipeline.AWSCodePipelineClient.invoke(AWSCodePipelineClient.java:2996)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.codepipeline.AWSCodePipelineClient.executePollForJobs(AWSCodePipelineClient.java:1990)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.codepipeline.AWSCodePipelineClient.pollForJobs(AWSCodePipelineClient.java:1961)
> at
> com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.AWSCodePipelineSCM.pollForJobs(AWSCodePipelineSCM.java:255)
> at
> com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.AWSCodePipelineSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(AWSCodePipelineSCM.java:191)
> at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:418) at
> hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1388) at
> hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1291) at
> hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:606) at
> hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:652) at
> hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:119)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you add the code for the jenkins job?

Comment: There is nothing at the moment. To make it simple, I just tried to execute the date in a variable and print it (echo) and comment out the original running script command. In build execute shell area only following two command are written.`code` now='date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"' echo $now

Comment: Yes these details should be added to the question. The goal is to make a [mre] so it is easier to come up with an answer you will accept.

Comment: sure added in the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that either the Jenkins Server is unable to connect to the CodePipeline service or the Jenkins server has some missing dependency with respect to AWS SDK for Java.

Can you SSH into the Jenkins Server and run the following AWS CLI command to confirm connectivity with CodePipeline service:

```
aws codepipeline poll-for-jobs --action-type-id=category=Test,owner=Custom,provider=Jenkins_November,version=1
```

[SSH Into a Linux Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

[Installing AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html)

Comment: The command responded with the "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PollForJobs operation: Expected a query param for 'ProjectName'"

Comment: I tried this instead with the project name parameter, I tried with project name on Jenkins server and project name on pipeline but both returns an empty array           
                                                                                                                                     
aws codepipeline poll-for-jobs --action-type-id=category=Test,owner=Custom,provider=Jenkins_November,v                                                                      ersion=1 --query-param=ProjectName=ProjectName

Comment: returns "{
    "jobs": []
}
"